# select nodes between two arbitrary tags in xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to extract all the nodes that are present between two arbitrary tag in XPath 1.0. Let me explain, starting from a tag I would take all the nodes up to a specific tag, which could be a sub-node of the first tag. 
Using the example below I hope to clarify my problem.

```
 <div id="A">
    <div id="B">
        <div class="C">
            <div class="D">
                <div class="E"/>ev  
                <img src="xxx"/>ev
            </div>
            <div class="F">
                <div class="G"/>
                <img src="yyyy"/>ev
            </div>
            <div class="H">
                <div class="I"/>
                <img src="zzz"/>ev
            </div>
            <div class="L"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to select all the nodes between the tag with id = "B" and the tag with class = "H" (with the node class = "H" excluded). 
I did some tests but I could not find a solution. For example i tried somethings like /div/div//*[.//* = div[@class='H']] but it doesn't works.

Comment: *I did some tests but I could not find a solution.*  Perhaps you can show what you have tried, and describe how it is failing you? Also, might be useful to know how you are doing this: php/javascript/vba/etc...

Comment: When you select the element with id `B`, you select the entire tree. You can then filter that tree. There is no way do represent the concept "*between*" id `B` and `H` in XML.

Comment: FYI: Your XML is invalid. What exactly does "between" mean? Do you want to go the textual way and select C, D, E, xxx, F, G and yyyy or do you want to go the tree way and select C only?

Comment: I have corrected the xml ;-) @Thomas W I want to select C, D, E, xxx, F, G and yyyy

Comment: @David Zemens i added an example of some xpath expression tried.

Comment: You may be able to do this in Xquery but I don't see a way to do it exactly in xpath. Does this help? `/div/div/div/*[not(@class='H' or @class='L')]`

Comment: I agree with helderdarocha. When you say node C, it's mean C and all it's descendant. That's just how nodes recognized in XPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only possible solution I found is to take the nodes D and F, given the semantics of XPath. So if I am asked in particular to take the nodes between id=B and class=H, I can write

$specification = /div/div

descend of two positions

$start = $specification /div/div

and finally ask nodes to H

$expression = $start /following-sibling::*[following::*[@class='H']

Thank you to all for the suggestions